# get data of parent DataList and assigning it to anchor tag in child DataList Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to asp.net.
I have a nested DataList and i want to assign the text of the label(parent ds) to the anchor href(child ds).

my code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="ddlpro" runat="server" onItemBound="dllpro">//parent ds
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="ImgName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("a1") %>' ></asp:Label>
<asp:DataList ID="ddlchild" runat="server" onItemBound="dllchild">//child ds
<a href='<%#Eval("a1") %>' ID=Btn><asp:Label>'<%#Eval("Idname") %>'</asp:Label>
.
.
All closing tags
```

how can i assign that label value to my link href??

Comment: You have an `ItemBound` event on your parent datalist. You can perform this on server where first you need to find your child datalist then after once found you can find your desired anchor tag using child datalist object and populate it with some value. Make sure the anchor tag have `runat=server` property.